# Reverse the order of space-separated words in a string

Tags: php, string, reverse

What would be the best way to reverse the order of space-separated words in a string?

```
Hello everybody in stackoverflow
```

becomes

```
stackoverflow in everybody Hello
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
$s = 'Hello everybody in stackoverflow';
echo implode(' ', array_reverse(explode(' ', $s)));
```

Answer (score 2):

In prose that is:

- First turn the string into an array of words

```php
$words = explode(' ', $string);
```

- Second, inverse the order of the elements in that array

```php
$reversed_string = implode(' ', array_reverse($words));
```

Reading the whole list of string and array functions in PHP is VERY helpful and will save tons of time.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer, strrev reverses the entire string. To reverse the order of the words:

```
$str = 'Hello everybody in stackoverflow';
$tmp = explode(' ', $str);
$tmp = array_reverse($tmp);
$reversed_str = join(' ', $tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$tmp = explode(' ', $string);
array_reverse($tmp);
$string = implode(' ', $tmp);
```