# PHP - swap the first and third word in a sentence with 3 words

Tags: php, replace, swap

If I have an input:

```
$input = "One Two Three";
```

How could I swap the first with the third word and have this output:

```
"Three Two One"
```

Comment: Are you sure that this sentence will always contains only three words and you always have to swap First to Three.

Comment: Did you try anything, or are you coming to get us do your homework ?

Comment: Use Split/Explode then concate 3rd + 2nd + 1st + rest...

Comment: If you'll always have three elements then you can explode the string and reverse the array. If you're looking for an in-built function to swap array elements in the general case, there isn't one - you'd need to use a temp variable or similar.

Comment: This unrealistic sample data represents a very ambiguous [mcve] and will lead to too many different approaches that will behave very differently in different scenarios.  Rhis question is Unclear.

Comment: By one interpretation, this question is a duplicate of [Reverse the ordering of words in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/715330/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$input = "One Two Three";
$words = str_word_count($input, 1);
$reversed_words = array_reverse($words);
print_r($reversed_words); // prints Array ( [0] => Three [1] => Two [2] => One )
```

Create string:

```
$input = implode(' ', $reversed_words);
echo $input; // "Three Two One"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer.

```
<?php
    $input = "One Two Three";
    $array = explode(' ',$input);
    krsort($array);
    $input = implode(' ',$array);
    echo $input;
?>
```

Comment: This is a very precise answer for a very specific problem :)
Anyway, this revert the order of the array; if the input contains more than 3 elements the result will be incorrect.

Comment: That's correct, I want to replace the first and last word in a sentence with 3 words, so thank you

Comment: This unexplained answer is very narrowly suited to the unrealistic sample text.  This technique will almost certainly not help researchers with similar requirements.